# Substitute baking containers

Tags: baking, substitutions, pan

I have a three-wheat batter bread recipe that calls for baking in four 16 oz cans. What size pan can I substitute?

Comment: Is the recipe on the web? If so, can you link to it? Is "16 oz" the only description?

Answer (score 1):

Three small (but not mini) metal loaf pans (5"L x 3"W x 3"D) will do it. Check out vintage bakeware in thrift stores to find that odd size, or choose pans closest to that size.

Comment: If you know if a place that uses the small-ish aluminum foil takeout containers, they're typically about 1 1/4#  (ie, 1.25lbs or 20oz)

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, use whatever size pans you have available to you and just monitor the baking process. Get creative.